# Hou to change CSS layout in a way, where middle div goes to the top?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to make responsive web page and I would like to place three divs in one column for small screens and in two for bigger one. The problem is that this does not looks so good, unless middle one goes to the top like this:

[image]

I got JFiddle with this example: https://jsfiddle.net/usr151/kjz0459a/5/

My question is how to do id in CSS (+bootstrap) the easiest way? I'm not very experienced in styling, so I would be glad for any advice and tools I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div3 col-md-6 order-md-2">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="div2 col-12">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="div1 col-md-6 order-md-2">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it Correct or you meant something else

Comment: Thanks a lot, I somehow missed class order-* and lost some time fighting with CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single container and sm/xl class :

example

```css
.div1 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cffadc;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #cfd4fa;
}

.div3 {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #faeacf;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="div1 col-12 order-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="div2 col-xl-7 col-sm-12 order-1">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="div3 col-xl-5 col-sm-12 order-0 order-xl-1">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```